# how do I make first half of array is random integers from 0 to 7, second half is random members from first half of array but can only be picked once

Tags: java, arrays, random

I want to make a 2d array that has for example {{2,5,5,2,4,7,6},{5,2,6,7,4,5,2}}
First half of array is random integers, second half of array is random members of first half of the array. This way I have pairs of every random number. This is my code so far, it gives me an array with random numbers. The part that I don't know how to do is the second half of array. Please help!

```
        private int[][] board;
        private int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        public Board() {
            board = new int[DEFAULT_SIZE][DEFAULT_SIZE];
            for (int i=0;i<board.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<board.length;j++) {
board[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
            }
            }
```

Comment: What you want is to _shuffle_ a copy of your original random list.  Check out the docs for [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-); you can either implement the same algorithm yourself, or just use `Collections.shuffle` if you don't mind the hassle of converting between arrays and Lists.

Comment: But how will I make an integer arraylist 2d? or how do I implement this on arrays? I'm confused I'm sorry

Comment: Assuming you just need the entire second half to be a shuffled version of the entire first half,  take _all_ the numbers from _all_ the rows of the first half and put them in a single `ArrayList` to be shuffled.  Then read the shuffled numbers out sequentially and distribute them into the rows and columns of the second half.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Random.nextInt() to get a random index and then use it to get the random number from the first array:

```
int randomIndex = Random.nextInt(arr.length);
int randomVal = arr[randomIndex];
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me random members of the array that can be duplicated, but I want random members only once, as if the second half of the array is the first half of the array but shuffled.

Comment: Then you can try this: Integer[] arr = {2,5,5,2,4,7,6}; Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr)).